# Segue from TableView to TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

Hello Everyone i have loaded a table from a plist and i am trying to go to next tableviewController and load the next content with **PLIST KEY** the same name as the selected row. This is my code but when i am doing the segue i am getting the content from 1st object of the plist for all the keys cant find the error

```
#pragma mark - Navigation
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ChannelList"]){

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    ChannelsViewController *cvc =segue.destinationViewController;


    cvc.currentChannel = [countriesArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plist dictionary has keys that are string value. Depending on how you implemented it (for example, if its row number only) you could access it like this:

```
plistList = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url]valueForKey:[@([path row]) stringValue];
```

Comment: Ok i think that worked but i cant move plistArray to next UITableView

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"OSMainStoryBoard" bundle: nil];
YourClassName *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourClassName"];


NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyPlist" withExtension:@"plist"];

controller.plistList = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url]valueForKey:path];

controller.plistArray = plistList.allKeys;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```